# How to get the signed angle of a quaternion on an arbitrary axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm trying to make an airplane controller, I am kind of aiming for something between arcade and realistic, so I want the plane to turn with a force proportional to the roll.

I haven't coded in any adjustments and I'm still prototyping the whole thing, but I encountered a problem with getting the signed rotation angle while using quaternions, I had a look at *[Determining if quarternion rotation is clockwise or counter clockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498263/determining-if-quarternion-rotation-is-clockwise-or-counter-clockwise)* here on SO but I am having trouble generalizing the solution to the (almost) arbitrary plane the rotation can be at.

What I made by now:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float desiredYaw = _yaw * _rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float desiredPitch = -_pitch * _rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        float rotationStepSize = _throttle * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        Quaternion toRotate = Quaternion.Euler(desiredPitch, 0, desiredYaw);
        Quaternion straighRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_transform.forward, Vector3.up );
        
        _rotation = _transform.rotation * toRotate;
        float turningForce = Quaternion.Angle( _rotation, straighRotation );

        _rigidbody.MoveRotation( _rotation );
        _rigidbody.AddTorque( turningForce * _rotationForce * rotationStepSize * Vector3.up );
        _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce( _speed * rotationStepSize * Vector3.forward );
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** I realized I'm calculating the turning force using the roll rather then the yaw, that was intended just wrong wording, corrected now.

Comment: "signed angle of a quaternion on an arbitrary axis" doesn't really make sense unless you have a particular vector whose position after/before rotation is of interest. If you're interested in that, concrete examples would be helpful in describing what you mean. Anyway, I'd start with `_rigidbody.AddTorque(_rotationForce * Mathf.Sin( Mathf.Deg2Rad * Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.up, _transform.up, _transform.forward) * Vector3.up);` and make adjustments from there like if you want to modify the result of `Mathf.Sin` to have different easing.

Comment: It's a little unclear what `_throttle` has to do with the rate the plane should be rolling, so I discarded that from the calculation. Also, using `AddTorque` with the default forcemode of `Force` already takes `time.fixedDeltaTime` into account so you don't need to include it.  See [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/802667/view.html) about `Force` mode  (this is about `AddForce` but also applies to `AddTorque`)

Comment: In any case, If that formula gives you a desirable result, let me know and I can write more about it as an answer below. Or I can offer other suggestions depending on how it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was exactly what I needed!
BTW throttle is just me really poorly naming the gas (idk how to call it in a plane...)

Comment: After sleeping on it I realized there's an even simpler way, see answer below, and don't forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you need is a factor that describes how downward the plane's right is, you can just use the y component of the plane's right for that. No need to bring in quaternions or even trigonometry. Explanation in comments:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // ...

    // Calculate how downward local right is in range [-1,1]
    // The more downward, the more tilted right the plane is
    //   positive = tilted right
    //   negative = tilted left
    float turnFactor = -_transform.right.y;

    // Could do things to modify turnFactor to affect easing here.
    // For instance, if turning rate should start slower then rapidly increase:
    //   turnFactor = Mathf.Sign(turnFactor) * turnFactor * turnFactor;

    // Use factor and _rotationForce member to calculate torque, apply along 
    //   global up. 
    // We expect to call this every fixed frame so we can just use the default
    //   ForceMode of ForceMode.Force which multiplies fixed delta time inside.
    _rigidbody.AddTorque(_rotationForce * turnFactor * Vector3.up);

    // ...
}
```